# laravel vue.js select list from database

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I just begun Vue.js and I have some issues with it:

I’m currently working with Laravel, a PHP framework.

I would like to do a select list for a research, i have different applications but there are all related to different countries. And when I select a country I would like that only apps with this country appear.

I used to use php but we have to reload the page each time and it’s not very quick and easy to use.

My main page is like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>VueJS</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
  <script src="/js/vue.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
     <div id="app">
    <div id="country">
     <select v-model="selectedcountry">
     <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.value">@{{ option.text }}
        </option>
     </select>
    <span>Sélectionné : @{{ selectedcountry }}</span>
 </div>
  <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>'
```

And my app.js :

```
new Vue({
   el: '#country',
   data: {
    selectedcountry: 'All Countries',
      options: [
      { text: 'All Countries', value: 'world' },
      { text: 'Denmark', value: 'denmark' },
      { text: 'France', value: 'france' },
    ]
  }
})'
```

And in my database my table is : "cards" with an attribute call "country".

My controller is :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Apps;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->has('Country')) {
            $apps = Apps::where('Country', $request->Country)->get();

            return view('index', compact('apps'));
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: How can you do **what**?

Comment: I would like to do a select list for a research, I have different applications but there are all related to different countries. And when I select a country I would like that only apps with this country appear.

Comment: ...once the user selects a country make an ajax request with the country, query the apps against the country, return the results and then loop through them to display them.

Comment: ok, but I don't understand how to use it. Before using vue.js I was doing like this : <option {{ request('Country', 'all') == 'world' ? ' selected=selected' : '' }} value="world"> World</option> .                                                                 
     But It reload the page each time. So with Ajax it will work ?

Comment: Essentially, yes. I would suggest having a look at https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step

Comment: yeah I already had a look at this serie, but he didn't explain how to connect with the DB.

Comment: You don't connect to the database with Vue.

Comment: My applications are in my database and they have an attribrute that's call "country" and I would like that when the select list is on "france" it shows only france's application.

Comment: Ok, well if you had it working before you started using Vue, would you be able to add your controller method(s) for getting apps by country?

Comment: Yeah it worked without vue but it's not "smooth" we have to reload the page each time...so we thought about using vue.js

Comment: Ok, cool. As I say if you can add you controller method(s) for selecting the apps by country, I might be able to help you out. Just so you know, Vue itself doesn't make the ajax request, at this point think of it more as a way to display the data

Comment: I would like it please, because I'm a little bit lost I admit.

Comment: ...please add your controller method(s) for selecting the apps by country

Comment: I wrote it below. thanks

Comment: You really need to spend some more time understanding Vue before you come and ask a non-question. Same goes for Laravel. You don't seem to have a clue what you're doing

Answer (score 0):

My controller is :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Apps;
 class SearchController extends Controller
{
  public function search(Request $request){
   if( $request->has('Country') ){
     $apps = Apps::where('Country',$request->Country)->get();
     return view('index',compact('apps'));      
   }        
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create vue component for your application. Working with component makes your code easier and well structured, also you are confusing yourself with `#country` and `#app` and you also need to define your form elements for vue.